# Bayesian Algorithm for sorting hotel reviews

Tags: sorting, bayesian, rating-system, review

i'm trying to find a Formula or algorithm to sort the most useful rating for a set of hotel reviews.

The thing is that i have in a determined place three different hotels that has the following information:

Hotel A: 124 reviews, 8.6 avg rating.
Hotel B: 10 reviews, 8.8 avg rating.
Hotel C: 1000 reviews, 8 avg rating.

i tried the algorithm used here:[What is a better way to sort by a 5 star rating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411199/what-is-a-better-way-to-sort-by-a-5-star-rating)

WR = (v * R + m * C) / (v + m)

But i'm not being able to reflect that the "score" should be higher for Hotel C, because the quantity of reviews is the biggest.

If i can get that solved, I imagine that the sort should be close to: 1) Hotel C; 2) hotel A and 3) hotel B.

Thank you!

Diego.-

Answer (score 0):

This seems a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42051530/4386193). It seems that to have the proper order you have to assign a predefined number of downvotes equal to the greatest number of reviews an item has, instead of summing the total number of votes of all items and dividing by the number of items as I had thought before. In python:

```
pretend_votes = [1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                                                                        
rating = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                                                                                             
def score(item_votes):                                                                                                  
  votes = [iv+pv for (iv,pv) in zip(item_votes,pretend_votes)]                                                        
  return sum(v*u for (v,u) in zip(votes,rating))/float(sum(votes))
```