# How can I sort by a weighted (Wilson/Bayesian) rating/review score using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, statistics, bayesian, rating

I currently have a list of restaurants similar to how Yelp works that have ratings from 1-5 and a total number of ratings.  When showing the restaurants to my users, I want to sort by a weighted combination of ratings and reviews so that a restaurant with 1 5 star rating doesn't outrank a restaurant with 20 5 star ratings and 10 4 star ratings.

I want to use something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411268/7754241, but since the mean vote changes everytime a new restaurant is added or a new review is added, I am unsure how to do this dynamically.

Is this possible to do this within a db.find().sort() MongoDB query?

Comment: have you tried doing an aggregation, and in the aggregation pipeline compute weighted score as a new field and sort by that.

Comment: No.  It's not a huge number of restaurants being sorted at once, so I was hoping I could do it within the query without creating any extra fields.