# PostgreSQL: five stars rating, ordering objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, rating

In my database users can add a vote from 1 to 5 stars to every groups.
Then I have to display a leaderboard by those votes.
What I was doing until now is to order them by votes average without a weight. This is not so nice because a group having 5.0 with 20 votes is before of a group having 4.9 avg and 10000 votes.

This is my votes table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS votes(
user_id BIGINT,
group_id BIGINT,
vote SMALLINT,
vote_date timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id)
```

This is how I sort them now:

```
SELECT 
      group_id,
      COUNT(vote) AS amount,
      ROUND(AVG(vote), 1) AS average, 
      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY s.lang ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(VOTE), 1)DESC, COUNT(VOTE)DESC)
FROM votes
LEFT OUTER JOIN supergroups AS s 
USING (group_id)
GROUP BY group_id, s.lang, s.banned_until, s.bot_inside
HAVING 
      (s.banned_until IS NULL OR s.banned_until < now()) 
      AND COUNT(vote) >= %s 
      AND s.bot_inside IS TRUE
```

How could I add a sort of weight to solve the problem I said before?

I read about bayesan approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411268) but I am not sure if it's the right thing because I read it's about to sort the top 'n' elements, while I have to do a leaderboard including anyone of them.

Comment: This post is going to be opinion based I'm guessing. There are lots of options and each has its merits. You could do a weighting system, you could not display it in ranks until is has 20/50/100 votes, etc. For example, I went to Amazon and searched Computer and the 5th result has under 20 reviews but has 5 stars.

Comment: @dfundako in fact as you can read in the query i used "AND COUNT(vote) >= %s" to avoid groups with few votes but i think i need something to weight them. i read about bayesan approach and wondering if can be good in my case

Comment: Ok, then set it up, dump a bunch of test data in there, and see if you like the ordering that results from it.

Comment: Why not just order by COUNT(VOTE)DESC instead? Then u will have the group with 4.9 come first.

Comment: @DanielMarcus i have to take into consideration also the average otherwise a group with 2.0 avg and 1000 will be on top and that's bad

Comment: ok so maybe you can assign a weight based on the number of digits in the votecount? so a votecount with 2 digits is worth .5 and a votecount with 3 digits is worth .7 and a vote count with 4 is worth .9 something like that

Answer (score 0):

you're going to have to fudge it somehow,
perhaps this way.

```
order by (0.0+sum(vote))/(count(vote)+log(count(vote)))
```

Or sqrt might work better than log, it depends how much weight you want the population size to have.

```
order by (0.0+sum(vote))/(count(vote)+sqrt(count(vote)))
```

basically the fudge needs to be a function that increases at a slower rate than it input. you could even try a constant.