# Calculate rate number average to 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a rate system (similar to imdb movie rate), result maximum is 10, It's mean output can be a number between 0 to 10. and should show like this (2/10)

User can rate from, 1 to 5 (starts), each user allowed for once.

So consider, this array is all users rates.

```
let rate = ['4', '5', '1', '2', '5', '5', '2', '1', '3', '3', '4']; // all users rates
let result = 0;

for (i = 0; rate.length > i; i++) {
  result += parseInt(rate[i]);
}

let av = result / 10;
```

It's working good, but the problem is, this output never reach to big rate, like 9 or 10. So I should make a target, right?, my ceil target is 1250, it's mean if all users rate total is 1250, user should get rate 10/10.

```
let av = 1250 / 10;
```

But this return 125 ofcourse.

**Target:** show all user rate like this, 5/10 or 7/10 like imdb rate.

Comment: you have 11 entries and an average of 10 ...?

Comment: This "system" makes no sense. If the highest vote is 5 then why is it a _"x of 10"_ rating? o.O

Comment: @NinaScholz I have many users, everyone can vote, from 1-to-5 stars, now a movie can have 100 different rates, but I want to show something like this `6/10`

Comment: result += parseFloat(rate[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already **divided by 2** the expected rating system 10 to **5 stars** - 
you need to back **multiply** the stars by 2 to return to the 10 system.

```js
// Convert 1-5 rating stars to 1-10 rating
const stars_to_ten = stars =>
   Math.round(stars.reduce((ten, star) => (ten += star * 2, ten), 0) / stars.length);

let result1 = stars_to_ten(['4', '5', '1', '2', '5', '5', '2', '1', '3', '3', '4']);
let result2 = stars_to_ten(['5', '5', '5', '5', '5']); 


console.log(result1); // 6
console.log(result2); // 10
```

IMDB weights its rating by other undisclosed factors - so perhaps it's not a mean or median of the votes cast, so a weighted **algorithm** can be still used.

> **Weighted rating by true Bayesian estimate**
>
> `(WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C`
>
> Where:
>   R = average for the movie (mean) = (Rating)
>   v = number of votes for the movie = (votes)
>   m = minimum votes required to be listed in the Top 250 (currently 25000)
>   C = the mean vote across the whole report (currently 7.0)

```js
const bayesianWeighted = (avg, totVotes, minVotesTop = 10, mean = 7.0) =>
  (avg * totVotes + mean * minVotesTop) / (totVotes + minVotesTop);
  
const calcRating = stars => {
  const avg = stars.reduce((a, v) => (a += +v * 2, a), 0) / stars.length;
  return Number(bayesianWeighted(avg, stars.length).toFixed(1));
};



// TEST
[
  [4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4], // 6.7
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],                   // 5.3
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],    // 4.5
  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],                   // 8
  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],    // 8.5
].forEach(r => console.log(calcRating(r)));
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411268/383904
- https://www.quora.com/How-does-IMDbs-rating-system-work

Comment: Thanks, but please read my comments under Nina Scholz answer, your answer is too/ if two users rate 5 star, movie get 10/10 , makes no sense

Comment: @dannycavanagh So, the above is absolutely correct. On some pages, if you hover such voting system - sometimes in a tooltip you can see the relevant number of persons that voted i.e: `10/10 from 3 votes` or `7/10 from 13 votes`. Otherwise - you might want a specific **algorithm** in place you did not mentioned.

Comment: Maybe this algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411268/4540183

Comment: @dannycavanagh maybe, who knows of today. That answer is from 2009. Do you have any specific algorithm in mind other than that one suggested? `rating = (R * v + C * m) / (v + m);`

Comment: No unfortunately like that, but As I said in comments, I think should set a ceil target, this means, if 200 number of rates be `200` and each of them rate five stars, so in total we got 1000, if total is 1000, output should be like this=> 10/10. or if total is 500, 5/10, I don't know this is a right logic or not.

Comment: @dannycavanagh Added an example, where the total rating of every movie in the database averages to `0.7` as the *mean*. Tweak the `minVotesTop` and `mean` as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the right average and multiply with two, because of 10 (wanted) divided by 5 (your five star system) and get the average of a system with ten.

```js
let rate = ['4', '5', '1', '2', '5', '5', '2', '1', '3', '3', '4']; // all users rates
let result = 0;

for (i = 0; rate.length > i; i++) {
    result += parseInt(rate[i], 10);
}

let av = result / rate.length;

console.log('average', av);
console.log((av * 2).toFixed(2), 'of 10');
```

Comment: But when rate is 10/10 ?

Comment: if all users rate with `5/5`.

Comment: Should not be like this, maybe never a movie get such rate, everyone should give 5/5 stars? makes no sense, that's mean a movie get two 5 star, it has 10/10? no should not be like this.

Comment: this part is not clear. what do you want in which case?

Comment: Consider imdb, if two users vote 5 stars, just two users, movie should get 10/10 ?? / the issue is I can't find right logic of imdb, I don't know it's right or not, but I think I should set a ceil target, if total of rates is 1000, this mean at least 200 users rated, and if total is 1000 or near to 1000 it should get 9/10 or 10/10, hope you understand me. If not, just consider how Imdb works.

Comment: where should the `10/10` came from?

Comment: @dannycavanagh [How does IMDb's rating system work?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-IMDbs-rating-system-work)

Comment: @NinaScholz when 200 users, votes 5 stars, 200x5=1000, total should be 1000

Answer (score 0):

```js
let rate = ['4', '5', '1', '2', '5', '5', '2', '1', '3', '3', '4']; // all users rates
let result = 0;

for (i = 0; rate.length > i; i++) {
  result += parseInt(rate[i]);
}

result = (result/rate.length)*2;
result = result.toFixed(2);

let rating = result+"/"+10;

console.log(rating);
```

Comment: `(result/rate.length)*2` == `result/rate.length*2` . Also, `result.toFixed(2)` will always add decimals, use 1 and `Number(result.toFixed(1))` to only have one decimal - when needed. Also `result+"/"+10` is less confusing and shorter when written as `result+"/10"`